# Overlaying water in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to overlay all water on a map with a .png file. I successfully managed to do this in Tilemill, but it's 1000GB when I try to export it, so this isn't an option.

I noticed it has been done before: https://roadtrippers.com/

But I can't seem to figure out how they placed the overlay on top of the water.

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roadtrippers is using [Mapbox Studio](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio) style rather than a TileMill style, so they aren't generating or uploading MBTiles, but creating styles that are rendered on-the-fly. The method for adding water textures is the same between the two.